# How can I create a process in Windows with administrator rights from another software in C++ but without being dependent on that software?

Tags: createprocess

Imagine that some software in your Windows PC needs to be run in a given time and it was supposed that it's user would start it, but he forgot to do it. And that software was supposed to run as administrator (i.e. with administrator rights). So, in order to garantee that the given software will be open at that time, you put a watchdog than can perform what the user should have done.

This is not exactly my situation, but that's what I need. It must work in C++ and I'm using Qt (though I think that will not make much difference).

I searched almost all files in MSDN about CreateProcess() and similar functions and saw some dozens of examples in the net, but till now I wasn't able to do what I want (in fact, I wasn't even capable of running the software, much less with the details).

It's important to notice that the watchdog is supposed to just open the software as administrator and immediately "forget it"; it should have no control and the opened software must not be in anyway dependent on the watchdog (e.g. if the watchdog is closed, the opened software continue to run normally).

I'ld be glad if somebody helps.

Momergil

Comment: So is your problem that you don't know how to call `CreateProcess`, that you don't know how to impersonate an administrator, or what? You need to be a little more specific about what is the exact problem you're running into. "I can't figure out how to do it" is too broad.

Comment: Well, I guessed I put everything very clear in explaining my situation \o/ and "I can't figure out how to do it" is too broad only when the "it" wasn't explained before telling it, and I explained what I want :)

In short, than: how can I run/create a process set with administrator rights from inside another software but without being dependent in anyway from the opener software? Or: how can I simulate , in a software, the user's action of opening a software with admin rights?

Comment: The problem is that you listed several different problems. If the problem is just "how to start a process as administrator", your answer is [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But that's only going to create more questions, as in "how do I fill in all the parameters", especially regarding Win32 security. If you ask me, you should write a script in one of the languages Windows accepts, and stick it into the process scheduler (don't remember what it's called) to be run as an administrator. Much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if a program requires Administrator Rights to run, then a user **with** Administrator Rights is required to install it.

This gives Administrator Rights to the program.

**Update:** Based on your comment about trying to get another process to run another application with Admin Rights, you should look into the following code:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

public static void ProcessStart(string fileName, string arguments) {
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments);
#if !PocketPC
  try {
    WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal pal = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
    if (pal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)) {
      Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
#else
  Process.Start(startInfo);
#endif
}
```

This code excludes [Microsoft PocketPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/default.aspx) devices and only executes if the person running the program is in the Administrator group.

What you would need to do is initiate a [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) for an account (on the PC you want to run your application on) that has Administrator rights and [Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that account to run your application.

There is a working example of how to do this on CodeProject entitled [User Impersonation in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14358/User-Impersonation-in-NET) that can give you a lot more information.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that I must install a software with Admin Rights; I must OPEN, RUN the software with admin rights from another software.

Comment: OK, I see what you are after. I edited my answer. If it helps, vote it up. If it answers what you are after, kindly mark it as the answer too.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the code, but it didn't work. Isn't it C#? I need something to work in C++. And istn't there any .h missing? Using windows.h and psapi.h only, the compiler didn't found this "System.Security.Principal", much less the functions ("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()", "Process.Start", etc.).

Comment: C++ developers are typically able to make C# code work with minor tweaks, but it can not be pasted directly in. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx#Y0) for C++ example code.

Comment: Hmm, ok; I'll give a better look at the link you provided. But I wasn't able to figure out exactly where the part of "opening the software without that one being dependent on it" enters in your code, specially because it doesn't mention any CreateProcess() function or something of the sort (and I have no idea of what this Process.Start() function is - not C++, yes?) and the link you provided seems to not talk about creating processes.

Comment: What you need to do is set the WindowsIdentity to the Administrator account. Once that is done, you can launch your other application any way you see fit. Just do not forget to remove the Administrator rights. It seems like, if you don't, other users will be admins, won't be able to access **their** emails, etc.

Comment: Hmm, no problems. The software in case is supposed to be the only and always running software of its computer.

But still the "launch your other application any way you see fit" is part of my problems. I've seen dozens of examples on how to create a  process/open a software in Windows and till now I was completely unsuccessful in doing it. So it's not only a matter of opening a software with administrator rights, but also a mater of opening the software.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not trivial or considered introductory. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608.aspx) should show you how to do just about all of it. Build a test application and write in that code (not copy-n-paste) so you know what it is doing.

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted, finally! But not using CreateProcess or similars, but ShellExecute, and after all the code you gave to me wasn't necessary because it's garanteed that the "master" software will always run as administrator. Thanks, anyway!